# Splinter browser automation select option

Tags: python, html, selenium, splinter

I am trying to do browser automation on :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en

I am able to simulate click on the button for next review list using:

```
button = browser.find_by_css("button.expand-button.expand-next")
button[1].click()
```

Next I want to select the option "Newest" to get the latest reviews. However this is not working . Any help appreciated.
Tried the below. However it doesn't expand the dropdown button.

```
button = browser.find_by_css("button.dropdown-menu")
button[0].click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not calling the `click` method. It should be:

```
button = browser.find_by_css("button.dropdown-menu")
button[0].click()
```

After that, you would need to click the "Newest" button:

```
button = browser.find_by_xpath("//button[jsl = 'Newest']")
button[0].click()
```

Comment: Lol .. i don't know how i missed that. Let me try and see...thanks :)

Comment: Sorry...I don't have enough reputation to up vote . I am new to stack overflow